# C submit command to server from client

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, udp

I have a client-server application which runs on UDP ( I need it UDP not tcp ).
A client can send a message to server and it's working fine and vice versa.
I want the client to be able to pass a message as "_connect game1 10" and trigger a function on the server correspondingly  which is called _connect(char *name, int num).
How can this be performed to analyse each command to trigger what command ? and is serialisation is a solution and how to implement it.

Comment: It sounds like you want to design an RPC system, but are unsure where to start.  You can either use an existing RPC system, or you can try to build your own, but as it is, this question is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I know how to use rpcgen and design it's structure. What I need is just know how to make it manually. It's a university project and I need a bit of help just to be able to call the function from server and perform it's operations

Comment: You should probably talk to your professor, then.  It's not a good question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something on the lines of the following steps
1. Create a message structure

```
    typedef struct info
    {
        char clientReq[MAX_LENGTH];
        char sub[MAX_LENGTH];
        u_int32_t value;
        u_int16_t end; //Set for the packet which closes the connection 

     }messageInfo;
```

On Client

1. Create socket and bind locally  //and connect to server socket(optionally)

   ```
   fd = socket( family, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 );
   //handle error
   struct sockaddr_in         peerV4;
   struct sockaddr_in         clientV4;
   rc = bind(fd,(struct sockaddr *) &clientV4,
                            sizeof clientV4);
   //error handling
   ```
2. Send the packet data to server.

   ```
       //update peer(server) socket info here
       peerV4.sin_family = AF_INET;
       peerV4.sin_port = htons(serverPort);
       peerV4.sin_addr.s_addr = "x.x.x.x";
       uint8_t *tBuf = (uint8_t *)malloc(sizeof (info)); //memset to zero
       info *pHeader = (info *)tBuf;
       pHeader->value = htonl(10); //local value to send
       pHeader->end = htons(0);
       pHeader->clientReq  = "connect";
       pheader->sub = "game1";
       sendto(serverSock, tBuf, sizeof(info),0
                                    ,(struct sockaddr *) &peerV4,
                                    sizeof(peerV4));
   ```
3. Send last packet and close local socket.

   ```
      pHeader->end = htons(1); // so the server closes the socket
      //send packet
      close(fd);
   ```

On Server
1. Create a UDP socket, bind to a local address wait for client to send you the data and use recvfrom

```
      fd = socket( family, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 );
      //bind socket
      uint8_t *recvBuf = (uint8_t *)malloc(sizeof(info));
      info *pheader = (info *)recvBuf;
      int currLen = recvfrom( fd, recvBuf,
                  mBufLen),0,(struct sockaddr *)&peerV4,
                     &sockaddrLen);
      //error handling
      if(currLen > 0)
      {
           if(htons(pheader->end) == 1)
             //close socket
           char *localSub = pheader->sub;
           char *localRecv = pheader->clientReq;
           //do something with the values on the server like
           if (strcasecmp(localRecv,"connect")     == 0) //pseudo
                connect(sub,pheader->value)
      }
```